# how to fetch specific number of characters before the pattern

Tags: sql, oracle

I have values like the below in my table:

```
SER : 3-576509910214, 4182 5979WM
```

I need to remove the white spaces first. then fetch the 8 numbers before or after the occurrence of matching string `'WM'`. I need the output for the above value as `'41825979'`. I need to fetch 8 numbers after each occurrence of 'WM'.

`WM` can occur anywhere in the string.

How can I do that in with an Oracle SQL query?

Comment: . . What do you really mean?  Your title says "before", one part says "before or after", and a third says "after".

Answer (score 1):

This will return a string of digits up to 8 long from such a string:

```
select replace(regexp_substr(replace(str, ' ', ''), '[0-9]{1,8}WM'), 'WM', '')
```

If you want *before* and *after*, just modify the pattern:

```
select replace(regexp_substr(replace(str, ' ', ''), '[0-9]{1,8}WM|WM[0-9]{1-8}'), 'WM', '')
```

Comment: Looks good, its working, +1. [Edit] Oh, I see: `8 numbers before or after the occurrence of matching string`. Dear anonymous, to help other, please write clearly what's wrong. Downvote alone is not helpful.

Comment: this seems to work for first occurrence of 'WM' . there can be multiple occurrences of 'WM' in the values of column. how would I fetch it for multiple occurrences of search pattern.

Comment: @jerry . . . Your question says nothing about multiple matches.  That question is quite different, and should be asked as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

To take 8 digits before or after WM (after spaces are removed), use following:

```
WITH Demo(t) AS
(
  SELECT 'SER : 3-576509910214, 4182 5979WM' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SER : 3-576509910214, 4182 5 979 WM' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SER : 3-576509910214,WM 4182 5979' FROM dual
)
SELECT
  REPLACE(COALESCE(
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(t, ' ', ''), '[0-9]{8}WM'),
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(t, ' ', ''), 'WM[0-9]{8}')
  ), 'WM', '')
FROM Demo
```